# How to Create a Bootable ISO from Folder Directory?

Tags: dvd, iso-image

A week ago borrowed Windows Operating system Dvd from my friend to install a new OS on my computer. And after installing it I also copied all the files of DVD to create a backup of it. So that I can also have one copy of my friend's DVD which I can use anytime to install. But after some days I realized that instead of copying files from that DVD I have to create a bootable iso file from it. And Now he also doesn't have the Dvd. So is there any way I can make a bootable iso from files copied from it.
Help me in solving this issue.

Comment: I suppose you could try and create an ISO out of it, then use Rufus, to create a bootable installation media but that is more work, then simply downloading a valid bootable ISO from Microsoft for free.

Comment: What is the version of Windows on DVD in question? Windows Vista/7/8/10? As user Ramhound suggested, you can simply download a valid ISO from Microsoft. However if you want to learn how to create bootable ISOs from the source, then you can use OSCDIMG tool which is part of Windows ADK. Windows ADK is a big download, so standalone OSCDIMG is available on third-party sites for download and it should just run file on Windows 7 and above. You will have to study the command line options applicable in your case be it Legacy only UEFI only or Legacy+UEFI multiboot.

Comment: Please see the documentation here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/oscdimg-command-line-options

Comment: Windows instructions here: In your case skip most of step 3 since you have the extracted files already, just be sure they are in the c:\windowsiso folder you created in step 1.>>>>http://michael.anastasiou.me/how-to-create-a-bootable-windows-dvd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally agree with you, downloading ISO from Microsoft and using a USB drive is a nice idea. And USB works really quickly as compared to DVDs. But what if the user wants to create bootable iso for Windows 7. In that case, you cannot download the iso from the Microsoft official website without the genuine product key.

And in that case, creating an ISO from Windows installation files would be a better option.

And Yes it depends on the user to user.

So if you want to create bootable iso from folder or files follow this guide:

1. Install ImgBurn tool
2. Click on create an image from files/folder
3. Now Select the folder directory
4. Now Make ISO image bootable
5. Configure advanced bootable settings

For more info, you can also follow the original [source link](https://www.buildsometech.com/2019/09/create-bootable-iso-folder-files.html).

That's it. By using these steps you can easily create an iso file & use it in USB.

Thanks.